# How do I add labels to resources in a GCP Deployment Manager script?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I would like to add labels to my GCP resources to make it clearer what they are used for. How might I do this with GCP Deployment Manager?

I found an example that suggested I could do it like so, but it did not work:

```
resources:
- type: compute.v1.instance
  properties:
    metadata:
      labels:
        deployment: goggles

  # More config here...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty old but just came across my searches, if still helps:

```
resources:
- type: compute.v1.instance
  name: client0021
  properties:
    zone: us-west1-a
    machineType: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ env["project"] }}/zones/us-west1-a/machineTypes/f1-micro
    metadata:
      items:
      - key: key1
        value: some
      - key: managed
        value: 'true'
    labels:
      managed: 'yes'
      other: 'no'
```